# Performant way to sort sensor data with python

Tags: python

Currently I am working on a project to record sensor-data from different sensors. They all come over the same channel and I have to sort them by sensor-ID. As there will be ten-thousands of datapoints I have to sort, I look for a performant way to sort.

As the datapoints are coming randomly I do not know which lists I have to create.

So my approach would be to add them all to one list like that

```
[("sensor-id a", "timestamp", "data"),
("sensor-id b", "timestamp", "data"),
("sensor-id c", "timestamp", "data"),
("sensor-id a", "timestamp", "data"),
("sensor-id a", "timestamp", "data"),
("sensor-id b", "timestamp", "data"),
("sensor-id d", "timestamp", "data"),
("sensor-id a", "timestamp", "data")
]
```

Afterwards I would make a dict with the sensor Ida to get a list of all received sensors. Then I would make for each element in the dict a subtuple with the sensor-ID as a Filter.

So my goal is to have a list for each sensor-ID where the received datapoints are included. It seems to me that there is a lot of filtering done and I think there is a much better way to do this? But how?

Comment: Well, have you tried collecting them all and then ``sort``'ing them?

Comment: I don't know about your use case. But if you have a lengthy stream of incoming data, you could also consider storing it in a database system and letting the database do the sorting and data management for you. Database Management Systems are usually highly optimized under the hood. Cassandra, for example, would be pretty much optimized for working with time series data. Just in case that might be applicable for you.